# Why isn't deleting of objects in std::map linear time? Or: What is the fastest way to delete objects in std::map?

Tags: c++, stdmap, c++98

Edit: Never do profiling with DEBUG builds... Once I switch to RELEASE there is no noticable delay and the times progress linear. Creating and deleting 1000000 objects then happens within 370 msecs total.

--

I have a map containing pointers to objects: `std::map<int, DummyObject *> myMap`
When I delete the map, I noticed that it seems to take longer the larger the map is--- exponentially so. I was expecting linear behaviour.

While a dry iteration through the map (without actually doing anything) behaves more or less linear, deleting the objects (without modifying the map!!) totally whacks out. Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour? And even more important: What can I do to speed things up? Because unfortunately I really have a case with 60000+ objects, and cleaning up my map is taking too long...

Here is the code:

```
class DummyObject
{
public:
     DummyObject() {}
    ~DummyObject() {}
};

void testSpeed( int iMapSize )
{
    const unsigned int uiStart = GetTickCount();

    typedef std::map<int, DummyObject *> T_MyMap;
    T_MyMap myMap;

    // Fill the map...
    for( int i = 0; i < iMapSize; i++ ) {
        myMap[i] = new DummyObject();
    }
    const unsigned int uiFilled = GetTickCount();

    // Dry iteration through the map...
    for( T_MyMap::const_iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++ ) {
        int i = 0;  // do something
    }
    const unsigned int uiIterate = GetTickCount();

    // Delete the map...
    for( T_MyMap::const_iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); it++ ) {
        delete it->second;
    }
    const unsigned int uiDeleted = GetTickCount();

    myMap.clear();
    const unsigned int uiCleared = GetTickCount();

    DebugText( arg( "MapSize: %1 --- ",   iMapSize )
             + arg( "filled:  %1 msecs; ", uiFilled  - uiStart )
             + arg( "iterate: %1 msecs; ", uiIterate - uiFilled )
             + arg( "deleted: %1 msecs; ", uiDeleted - uiIterate )
             + arg( "cleared: %1 msecs; ", uiCleared - uiDeleted )
             + arg( "total:   %1 msecs; ", uiCleared - uiStart ) );
}
```

When I call this...

```
testSpeed( 100 );
testSpeed( 1000 );
testSpeed( 10000 );
testSpeed( 100000 );
testSpeed( 1000000 );
```

... this is the output I get:

```
MapSize:     100 --- filled:      0 msecs; iterate:    0 msecs; deleted:     16 msecs; cleared:    0 msecs; total:       16 msecs;
MapSize:    1000 --- filled:     31 msecs; iterate:    0 msecs; deleted:     15 msecs; cleared:    0 msecs; total:       46 msecs;
MapSize:   10000 --- filled:    203 msecs; iterate:   16 msecs; deleted:     47 msecs; cleared:   15 msecs; total:      281 msecs;
MapSize:  100000 --- filled:   2527 msecs; iterate:  250 msecs; deleted:   1435 msecs; cleared:  234 msecs; total:     4446 msecs;
MapSize: 1000000 --- filled:  34055 msecs; iterate: 2652 msecs; deleted: 172241 msecs; cleared: 1981 msecs; total:   210929 msecs;
```

Comment: I'd sooner blame the allocator than the map. What result do you get with a plain c array?

Comment: I think the calculation is off `+ arg( "deleted: %1 msecs; ", uiDeleted - uiFilled )` should be `+ arg( "deleted: %1 msecs; ", uiDeleted - uiIterate ) `

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with Adrian's comment above. Also, it appears to be very implementation-dependent: on my tests in XCode 6, I got more or less linear  results for all profiled operations. (I am not posting the actual data as a comment, as formatting is a pain)

Comment: Can't replicate on win8 with gcc 4.9.1 (total time), are you sure you are enabling optimizations?

Comment: Clang 3.5 on Mac OS gives `MapSize: 1000000 --- filled:  431 msecs; iterate: 29 msecs; deleted: 178 msecs; cleared: 259 msecs; total:   868 msecs`.  Even with optimization disabled it only takes 2-3 times as long as that.  This is on a pathetic 1.6 GHz laptop from 3 years ago.

Comment: @Niall, well spotted! Fixed that (though it does not really change anything). My problem seems to be an issue with DEBUG vs. RELEASE build. Added an explanation on top.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler did not optimize the "iterate" loop by ... removing it?

Comment: Do you mention your compiler? Visual Studio has a notoriously slow map implementation in debug mode. You can fix it by going to project settings > debugging and set Environment to `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` This is needed even in a release build, if you run your program through Visual Studio (F5 key)

Comment: @VAndrei: As you can see by the timings, the compiler didn't remove the "do nothing"-iteration. Other (smarter) compilers might do so.

Comment: @NeilKirk: It's RADStudio2007 in my case. RADStudio uses Dinkumware's STL implementation, AFAIK. Release build is fine, much to my relief.